# Postgres Extremely Slow Nested Loop

Tags: sql, postgresql

Thanks in advance!

I have to perform a join on a huge table (100+ million rows) on some smaller tables, mostly by date and a field called "symbol". The join, whereas my intuition would say should be rather efficient, seems to have a projected time of....years (!!) based on an EXPLAIN. Does anyone have any recommendations?

The query:

```
create table joinedcalls as
  select
    small_table_A.factor_A_date,
    small_table_A.factor_A_,
    split_data.factor_A_adjmultiplier,
    round(coalesce (factor_A_adjmultiplier, 1) * small_table_A.factor_A_, 2) as adjustedfactor_A_,
    calls.*,
    small_table_B_data.effr as small_table_Brate
  from calls
  inner join
    small_table_B_data
  on
    calldatadate = small_table_B_data.date
  inner join
    small_table_A
  on
    callunderlyingsymbol = small_table_A.symbol
  left join
    split_data
  on
    callunderlyingsymbol = split_data.symbol
  and
    calldatadate < split_data.splitdate
  and
    split_data.splitdate < small_table_A.factor_A_date
  where
    small_table_A.factor_A_date > calldatadate
  and
    (select count(*) from calendar
    where calldatadate < calendar.validdate
    and calendar.validdate <= factor_A_date) < 30
  and
    callexpiration > small_table_A.factor_A_date
  and
    small_table_A.status = 'Verified'

;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=207.14..181915836668.14 rows=154674305 width=121)"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=206.86..181867512643.56 rows=154636173 width=84)"
"        Join Filter: (split_data.splitdate < small_table_A.factor_A_date)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=206.58..181819575411.48 rows=154636173 width=78)"
"              ->  Index Scan using calls_calldatadate_idx on calls  (cost=0.57..6283903.98 rows=193651600 width=68)"
"              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on small_table_A  (cost=206.01..938.86 rows=1 width=14)"
"                    Recheck Cond: (((symbol)::text = (calls.callunderlyingsymbol)::text) AND (factor_A_date > calls.calldatadate) AND (calls.callexpiration > factor_A_date))"
"                    Filter: (((status)::text = 'Verified'::text) AND ((SubPlan 1) < 30))"
"                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=206.01..206.01 rows=3 width=0)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on small_table_A_symbol_idx  (cost=0.00..0.59 rows=23 width=0)"
"                                Index Cond: ((symbol)::text = (calls.callunderlyingsymbol)::text)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on small_table_A_factor_A_date_idx  (cost=0.00..205.17 rows=20475 width=0)"
"                                Index Cond: ((factor_A_date > calls.calldatadate) AND (calls.callexpiration > factor_A_date))"
"                    SubPlan 1"
"                      ->  Aggregate  (cost=243.88..243.89 rows=1 width=8)"
"                            ->  Seq Scan on calendar  (cost=0.00..243.72 rows=63 width=0)"
"                                  Filter: ((calls.calldatadate < validdate) AND (validdate <= small_table_A.factor_A_date))"
"        ->  Index Scan using split_data_symbol_idx on split_data  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=14)"
"              Index Cond: ((calls.callunderlyingsymbol)::text = (symbol)::text)"
"              Filter: (calls.calldatadate < splitdate)"
"  ->  Index Scan using small_table_B_data_date_idx on small_table_B_data  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=9)"
"        Index Cond: (date = calls.calldatadate)"
```

Comment: "rows=154674305" Are you sure that you want to select so many rows?

Comment: The outputted table will have far less rows (since there are several WHERE criteria) but I don't (at least right now) see a way to chop down that number of rows without having the information from the other tables.

Comment: Have you tried running it? Maybe your intuition is right.  Cost estimates are in arbitrary units, how did you convert that to "years"?

Comment: How do you know the query would take years? The cost value has nothing to do with the actual runime. Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure without testing it but : maybe you can chop-off your first loop by defining more accurately the data target definition (from clause) of your query :

```
create table joinedcalls as
select
    small_table_A.factor_A_date,
    small_table_A.factor_A_,
    split_data.factor_A_adjmultiplier,
    round(coalesce (factor_A_adjmultiplier, 1) * small_table_A.factor_A_, 2) as adjustedfactor_A_,
    calls.*,
    small_table_B_data.effr as small_table_Brate
from calls
    inner join small_table_B_data
        on calldatadate = small_table_B_data.date
    inner join small_table_A
        on callunderlyingsymbol = small_table_A.symbol
        and small_table_A.status = 'Verified'
        and callexpiration > small_table_A.factor_A_date
        and small_table_A.factor_A_date > calldatadate
        (
            select count(*) 
            from calendar
            where calldatadate < calendar.validdate
            and calendar.validdate <= factor_A_date
        ) < 30
    left join split_data
        on callunderlyingsymbol = split_data.symbol
        and calldatadate < split_data.splitdate
        and split_data.splitdate < small_table_A.factor_A_date;
```

For more explanation on the running order of a SQL query/statement : https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution

Remember also that the order of the table in the from clause have its importance though. (larger the first called table will be: larger will be the treatment time) So put the smaller table possible first.